# how to configure an AD FS server with OpenLDAP as the user database

Tags: openid-connect, adfs, openldap

We want to use OpenLDAP as a user database and authenticator behind ADFS.
our application (azure devops) just use ADFS or localuser on windows but our users on OpenLDAP.

what should we do ?

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify "use OpenID Connect as a user database".

OIDC is a protocol, not a repository.

ADFS supports the OIDC protocol but it uses AD as the repository.

**Update**

ADFS can also authenticate against users in an [LDAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-to-authenticate-users-stored-in-ldap-directories).

Note that the LDAP needs to be v3-compliant.

Comment: thank you for your response, I've change my question.